Why aren't custom HTML templates and inputs working within Shiny modules?
I'm encountering issues accessing inputs within Shiny modules where the UI is defined using either HTML templates or manually created HTML tags/inputs. Specifically, I can't access the input values from the server-side of the module when using these custom approaches. This issue affects both navigation and input handling.
Below is a simple reproducible Shiny app that demonstrates the problem:
In this example, I have two buttons in my Shiny app: one created with actionButton() and the other manually using tags$button in HTML. Both buttons are supposed to perform the same action, which is navigating to another module (mod2). While the Shiny button works as expected, the custom HTML button doesn't trigger the navigation.
library(shiny)

# Module 1 UI
mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h2("Module 1"),
    actionButton(ns("button1"), "Shiny Button 1"), 
    tags$div(
      tags$button(id = ns("button2"), "Custom HTML Button 2", class = "btn btn-primary") 
    )
  )
}

# Module 1 Server
mod1_server <- function(id, change_page) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$button1, {
      change_page("mod2")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
      change_page("mod2")
    })
  })
}


# Module 2 UI
mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h1("Module 2")  
  )
}

# Module 2 Server
mod2_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  })
}


# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("dynamic_ui")  
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  current_page <- reactiveVal("mod1")
  
  output$dynamic_ui <- renderUI({
    if (current_page() == "mod1") {
      mod1_ui("mod1_ui")
    } else {
      mod2_ui("mod2_ui")
    }
  })
  
  mod1_server("mod1_ui", change_page = current_page)
  mod2_server("mod2_ui")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)





You have to change the id of the inserted inputs by prepending the module namespace. ie for example in template 1, input id should be "mod1-input2"

I can't get any values out of your templates in a non-modularised version of your MRE, so there is evidently something to fix with that first. https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/building-inputs/ should be useful

@Billy34 I’ve rewritten the question. Hopefully, this version provides more clarity on the issue.

@smartse  I’ve rewritten the question. Hopefully, this version provides more clarity on the issue.

You need to assign the CSS class action-button for this to work:
library(shiny)

# Module 1 UI
mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h2("Module 1"),
    actionButton(ns("button1"), "Shiny Button 1"), 
    tags$div(
      tags$button(id = ns("button2"), type="button", "Custom HTML Button 2", class = "btn btn-primary action-button") 
    )
  )
}

# Module 1 Server
mod1_server <- function(id, change_page) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$button1, {
      change_page("mod2")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
      change_page("mod2")
    })
  })
}


# Module 2 UI
mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h1("Module 2")  
  )
}

# Module 2 Server
mod2_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  })
}


# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("dynamic_ui")  
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    print(names(input))
  })
  
  current_page <- reactiveVal("mod1")
  
  output$dynamic_ui <- renderUI({
    if (current_page() == "mod1") {
      mod1_ui("mod1_ui")
    } else {
      mod2_ui("mod2_ui")
    }
  })
  
  mod1_server("mod1_ui", change_page = current_page)
  mod2_server("mod2_ui")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Btw. why don't you use actionButton() and style it instead?

From your explanation, it seems that without these classes or proper integration, Shiny wouldn't be able to handle the inputs/outputs, right?" Thanks!!

On startup shiny scans the UI for inputs it needs to bind to make them available on the server side. Therefore, these input elements need to be marked.
